# Conditional Directory Index In Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

This relates to the question in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599717/conditional-directoryindex-in-htaccess

The answer states that the following should work:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^127\.0\.0\.0$ owner
<IfDefine owner>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !owner>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfDefine>
```

I am not sure this works, the setting of the Env var deffinately does, but no matter what IP I visit the site from the DirectoryIndex is always index.php

Is there something wrong with the conditional or should I be using something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up using the following to achieve what I wanted

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index.php

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111$
RewriteRule index.php$ index.html
```

Thanks!